# ASP.net MVC Android action redirect not working http to https

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

We have an asp.net mvc2 application.  I have the default route set to hit an action called SecureRedirect.  When a user goes to http://www.mydomain.com, the default route is invoked, calling the SecureRedirect action which does a simple:

```
return redirect("https://www.mydomain.com/secure/showlogin").
```

Notice how i'm calling the site via https in the action.  This works perfectly fine in all PC based browsers i've tested.  It works fine on my iPhone and iPad but it's not working for Android devices like the DroidX or Samsung Galaxy (android based) tablet.  I'm logging the SecureRedirect action and i'm finding Android never hits the action while iOS devices and PC browsers do.

This doesn't make sense to me as these Android devices are running WebKit, the same as on iOS devices.

Can anyone shed light on this?  I would prefer to handle the redirect using actions instead of creating a default.aspx page with a hard coded redirect to https.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to reproduce but 2 things i will say to ensure you do it the real asp.net mvc way.

Assuming that your controller is named "secure" and the action in the secure controller is named "showlogin",

1. Redirect to your action using

   ```
   public ActionResult SecureRedirect()
   {
        UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
        return Redirect(u.Action("showlogin", "secure", null, "https"));
   }
   ```
2. Decorate your "showlogin" action method with the `[RequireHttps]` Attribute to ensure https. like this

   ```
   [RequireHttps]
   public ActionResult showlogin()
   {
      ....
   }
   ```

**hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  All of my actions already implement [RquireHttps] but Androids don't respect it.  Unfortunately, Androids don't hit my SecureRedirect at all, so using RedirectToAction won't help.  


Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. It is really strange that only the android browser does that. Really hard to reproduce, could you provide more informations or an live url so we can test that on android devices ?

Comment: tell me about it.  if i call the site, using an android, with http instead of https, it just hangs and hangs returning a page not found error, iOS devices no problem.  i'll ping you the URL.  Thanks again

Comment: again, realy strange. ;) damn your in boston and i am in germany.. the time difference ;) i need some sleep but i would love to help you. Please send me an url so i / we can test that on our mobile devices. Have a nice day! See you later